# why this regular expression match this?

Tags: python, regex, nsregularexpression

[image]

I want to find the part which has a form like ( float), so I use the expression above.

But it matchew with `'b' :(0, 2074.5)`, which is not what i think, because it has colon. To find the part which has only one float, how can i write my regular expression in python?

Comment: `.` is a meta character is regex, and it means match anything except new line, so in regex you have `.+` which means match anything except new line one or more time

Comment: Paste the expression [here](https://regex101.com).

Answer (score 0):

Kim, in this case, "." is a regular expression meaning anything. if you want to find the "."  in the text, you must escape it like this `\.`

to find only the float in `'b' : (0, 2074.5)` you should use the following Regex:

`(\d+\.\d+)`

Hope this will help.